# java.lang.ClassCastException while trying to deserialize object with List as parameter

Tags: scala, deserialization, classcastexception

I am trying to serialize and then deserialize an object that contains List[user defined class] as an argument. It keeps throwing java.lang.ClassCastException. However, the code works when List is of Int or String. I think there is some problem in resolving classes but I am unable to fix it.

```
object WriteTestObject {
    class A
    case class B (n:String) extends A
    class C
    case class D (args:List[B]) extends C
    def main(args: Array[String]) ={
        val x = B("some String")
        val y = D(List(x))
        val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"))
        oos.writeObject(y)
        oos.close()
        val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("out.txt"))
        val ob = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[B]
        print(ob)
        ois.close()

    }
 }
```

output:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
>   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field
>   WriteTestObject$D.args of type scala.collection.immutable.List in
>   instance of WriteTestObject$D

Comment: you should change `ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[B]` to `ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[D]`

Comment: I did that, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you try if the solution from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ramn/5566596) helps? It seems to be Scala/Java error. I could reproduce it using scratch in IntelliJ, but not in normal class nor shell.